# Como juntar textos em um arquivo?

Tags: python-3.x

Eu estou tentando desenvolver um programa, que faz o seguinte:

De 1 até 100, ele escreve em um arquivo de texto a palavra "teste".

E após isso, eu quero que ele junte a palavra "teste" DE CADA LINHA com as respectivas linhas de outro arquivo de texto.

Eu executei o programa, e ele escreveu 100 linhas com a palavra "teste", porém, não sei como juntar com cada linha do outro arquivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para juntar com cada linha deste outro arquivo de texto?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tendo como resultado isso(não fiz até 100, porque é muito trabalhoso):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código fonte:

```
arquivo = open('arquivo_teste.txt', 'w')
outro_arquivo = open('letras aleatórias.txt', 'w')

for i in range(0, 100):

    """ 
        Preciso escrever em cada linha "teste" + o conteúdo de cada linha do outro arquivo. 

        No caso, "outro_arquivo", ali de cima.
    """
    arquivo.writelines('teste')

    # Usei para dar espaço(um embaixo do outro) e não ficar deste jeito: 
    # testetestetestetestetestetestetestetestetestetesteteste 
    arquivo.write('\n')

arquivo.close()
outro_arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Tu já tens os dois ficheiros preenchidos com as 100 linhas? Só falta saber como juntar ambos os conteúdos certO?

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para escrever nos ficheiros (esta parte já tens):

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_lowercase

print('\n'.join('teste' for _ in range(100)), file=open('1.txt', 'w'))
print('\n'.join(''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 10)) for _ in range(100)), file=open('2.txt', 'w')) # escrever no ficheiro letras aleatorias
```

De resto, há várias maneiras de fazer:

#### 1.

Esta talvez fosse a que eu usaria

```
together = ''
with open('1.txt') as f1, open('2.txt') as f2:
    for linha_teste, linha_letras in zip(f1, f2):
        together += '{}{}'.format(linha_teste.strip(), linha_letras)
```

#### 2.

```
together = ''
with open('1.txt') as f1, open('2.txt') as f2:
    for l in f1:
        together += '{}{}'.format(l.strip(), f2.readline())
```

#### 3.

```
with open('1.txt') as f1, open('2.txt') as f2:
    together = ''.join('{}{}'.format(f1.readline().strip(), f2.readline()) for _ in f1)
```

#### 4.

```
together = ''
with open('1.txt') as f1, open('2.txt') as f2:
    linhas1 = f1.readlines() # obter uma lista com cada linha
    linhas2 = f2.readlines() # obter uma lista com cada linha
    for idx, l1 in enumerate(linhas1):
        together += '{}{}'.format(l1.strip(), linhas2[idx])
```

Depois para veres o conteúdo podes:

```
print(together)
```

Comment: Miguel, vi que você alterou as soluções.

Comment: Estou a melhorar e acresentar mais @BRKappa

Comment: Eu fiz um dois tipos de script pra fazer o que eu queria(editei de acordo com a sua primeira solução de antes). Vou deixar no pastebin, porque não sei como formatar pelo comentário! https://pastebin.com/ATvpJHnT
https://pastebin.com/jbUcY3PP

Comment: QUalquer uma deve dar

Comment: De acordo com o que editei, você acha que ficou melhor, qual? Digo, boas práticas, e código limpo? Sou iniciante, por isso não entendi muito alguns códigos, então, desculpe pelos erros. Mas, você conseguiu chegar no que eu queria!! :)

Comment: Ah, e quando eu abro o arquivo com "With", eu tenho que fechá-lo com o close() ou não precisa?

Comment: Coloquei na resposta @BRKappa, a numero 2 talvez

Comment: Não é preciso @BRKappa, quando sais da indentação o ficheiro é fechado, não precisas do `close()`

Comment: Opa, obrigado! Me ajudou a solucionar todas minhas dúvidas!!

Comment: De nada @BRKappa, ainda bem

Comment: @BRKappa aliás, eu usaria a 1 e não a 2, mas são iguais, só mesmo por uma questão de leitura

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de fazer é: Abra um outro arquivo em branco e vá lendo as linhas em sequencia de cada arquivo e concatene a linha 1 do arquivo 1 com a linha 1 do arquivo 2 e dê um **add** no arquivo 3 e assim por diante com as outras linhas.